# Load File In REPL is not available

Tags: eclipse, clojure, counterclockwise

I am following the basic intro [here](http://dev.clojure.org/display/doc/Getting+Started+with+Eclipse+and+Counterclockwise). Everything is fine until I go to use <kbd>Command-Option-S</kbd> which does nothing -- and the "Load File in REPL" in the Clojure menu is grayed out and not selectable.

What is the fix for this?

In the same menu, the two other options for working with the REPL are also unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure leiningen is installed and in your PATH.  When you first run "load file", give the REPL some time to start.